# Pandas query with double index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble using boolean indexing from pandas query for dataframes with double column index.

I have the following dataframe:

```
df2 =

        val1            val2
        mean    size    mean    size
col1                
    c   2.5        2    5   2
    d   4.5        2    9   2
    e   0.5        2    1   2
```

where val1, and val2 are first level column indexes and mean and size are the second level indexes.

Then I want to select rows with the first column ('val1','mean') > 3 using syntax like this:

```
df2.query('(val1, mean) > 3')
```

I know it can be done by

```
df2[df2[('val1','mean')] > 3],
```

but I want to know whether it's possible in query since the syntax is more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

isin returns a boolean Series and ~ negate the boolean Series

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['column_name'] in x['column_name'], axis=1)
```

Instead of 'in' you can put your condition such as >3

```
df.loc[~df['column_name'].isin(some_values)]
```

or

```
df['column_name'] >=  3
```

Yes, there is possibility to perform it by the aid of 'query'

```
df.query('(a < b) & (b < c)')
```

[pydata: indexing-query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#indexing-query)

[pandas.dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want to know whether there is a way in query to support that......

Comment: @Jason I updated answer, please accept if it helped.